# Site Workflow Sharepoint 2010 calculate and ouput to field not variable

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create a site workflow to add a date to every document in the site.

I added a calculation action to a SharePoint 2010 Site Workflow.  The only output offered is to workflow variable.  However I can't see any way to add this to the column I've created in the document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a variable to a field of the current item you can use `Update field in current element` or `Update item of this list`.